# How to set minimum width of outlook Right Side Pane in Inspector and Explorer window

Tags: c#, .net, outlook, outlook-addin, addin-express

I have created a outlook addin using `addin-express`. When I drag the addin from  right pane to bottom pane and reduce its height into 2 digits e.x 40px. and drag it  back to right side, the right pane width is getting set to really small value.

To fix this I am setting the Width to a certain value in form resize event handler which works for explorer window. But in Inspector window the right pane width still gets set to a very small value.

Is it a correct way set minimum width for Pane in `Resize` event handler? If not How to set minimum width of `Panes`?

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest setting the form region's state by setting the `RegionState` property for getting it minimized.

[image]

Also, you may find the `ADXBeforeDrag` event of the ADXOLForm class helpful. It is fired before the form is dropped onto another region.

At any point in time, you may get the current layout by using the `ExplorerLayout` or `InspectorLayout` properties. Depending on the layout set you may resize your form.

Comment: I am using Addin-express version 8.9.4453. and looks like `ADXBeforeDrag` is available for version 9.1.4 and beyond. are you aware of any other alternative?
https://vs.componentsource.com/news/feature-releases/2018/06/22/add-in-express-net-office

Comment: In the `Resize` event you may check the current region layout. Does it work? Do you get a new layout?